# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm implementing a feedback side panel.
It is possible tp have more forms on the view, so I have to specify the id of this form.
Once I do this, the script is giving me problems.

It says:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Any ideas?

This is my partial view code.

```
@model project.FeedbackViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Feedback";
}

<h2>Feedback</h2>

<div id="result"></div>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "feedbackform" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>User:</p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</p>
    <p>Email:</p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserEmail, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</p>

    <p>Message:</p>
    <p>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @cols = 80, @rows = 10 })</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#feedbackform').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Add jquery reference.

Comment: jQuery is most likely loaded after your inline javascript is executed. So either put your code into a js file and include it after jquery is included or load jquery earlier e.g. in the header element of your main html template.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add references to jquery.  that's a jquery script.  you can reference them directly from the CDN.

Comment: I have that in the bundle in the main page.

Comment: It says: (anonymous function)